# Webcrawler: read out html-tags with specific parents

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I want to crawl all IDs to set them one after another into my_url. To get the li data-id works fine, but I also want to get the a data-go-to-expose-id. I have tried different things, but nothing works.

The html:

```
<ul id="resultListItems" class="is24-res-list is24-res-gallery result-list border-top">
    <li class="result-list__listing result-list__listing--xl" data-id="102292896">
        <div>
            <article data-item="result" id="result-102292896" data-obid="102292896" class="result-list-entry result-list-entry--xl result-list-entry--project result-list-entry--with-logo" data-listing-size="XL">
                <div class="result-list-entry__grouped-listings">
                    <div class="slick-initialized slick-slider">
                        <div aria-live="polite" class="slick-list draggable">
                            <div class="slick-track" style="opacity: 1; width: 356px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
                                <div class="grouped-listing slick-slide slick-current slick-active grouped-listing--active" style="width: 162px;" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false">
                                    <a href="/expose/102292896" id="result-102292896" data-go-to-expose-id="102292896" data-go-to-expose-referrer="RESULT_LIST_GROUPED">
```

The script:

```
(...)
try:
    get_id = soup(url, "html.parser")

    for biglist in get_id.find_all("li", {"data-id": True}):
        if (biglist.parent.get("id") == "resultListItems"):
            my_url = "https://www.abc.de/"+biglist.get("data-id")+"#/"
            (...)
```

This part works fine, but the next one not.

```
    for list1 in get_id.find_all("a", {"data-go-to-expose-id": True}):
        if (list1.parent("div", "class") == "grouped-listing"):
            my_url2 = "https://www.abc.de/"+list1.get("data-go-to-expose-id")+"#/"
            (...)
```

How can I do, that it searches first for the "li"-IDs and second for the "a"-IDs? The second part don't find any results. It's maybe becau the parent div class ist more than "grouped-listing"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search for all `<a>` tags with attribute `"data-go-to-expose-id"`, whose parent is `<div>` with class `"grouped-listing"`, you can use CSS selector

```
'div.grouped-listing a[data-go-to-expose-id]'
```

, like this:

```
data = """
<ul id="resultListItems" class="is24-res-list is24-res-gallery result-list border-top">
    <li class="result-list__listing result-list__listing--xl" data-id="102292896">
        <div>
            <article data-item="result" id="result-102292896" data-obid="102292896" class="result-list-entry result-list-entry--xl result-list-entry--project result-list-entry--with-logo" data-listing-size="XL">
                <div class="result-list-entry__grouped-listings">
                    <div class="slick-initialized slick-slider">
                        <div aria-live="polite" class="slick-list draggable">
                            <div class="slick-track" style="opacity: 1; width: 356px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
                                <div class="grouped-listing slick-slide slick-current slick-active grouped-listing--active" style="width: 162px;" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false">
                                    <a href="/expose/102292896" id="result-102292896" data-go-to-expose-id="102292896" data-go-to-expose-referrer="RESULT_LIST_GROUPED">
"""


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

for a in soup.select('div.grouped-listing a[data-go-to-expose-id]'):
    my_url2 = "https://www.abc.de/"+a['data-go-to-expose-id']+"#/"
    print(my_url2)
```

This prints:

```
https://www.abc.de/102292896#/
```